# Error when using jqGrid getChangedCell method

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I'm using jqGrid  4.3.2, that contains  grid.base.js; jquery.fmatter.js; grid.custom.js; grid.common.js; grid.jqueryui.js modules.

when calling method getChangedCells

```
var modified = $("tableau").jqGrid('getChangedCells', 'all');
```

I've got this error :

> Uncaught jqGrid - No such method: getChangedCells

do I need un other module to make this working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what you do. If you have error like `"No such method"` you should include the *full list* of JavaScript files in the exact order which you use. The method [getChangedCells](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#methods) is defined in `grid.celledit.js` module (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.celledit.js#L459)). It seems that you don't loaded the module.

Comment: Actually I'm using _struts2-jquery plugin taglib_ on my jsp page :
`<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>`
And I didn't know if he import all the required modules or not, but by debugging on FireBug, I found that the js files imported contains only the modules : grid.base.js; jquery.fmatter.js; grid.custom.js; grid.common.js;
There is a way to make truts2-jquery plugin import `grid.celledit.js` or I have to do this by myself?

Comment: @user1810097: I don't use `struts2-jquery` plugin myself and have no idea how it works and which modules it loads and why, but if it uses original code of jqGrid you should be able to see there in debugger. Like I wrote before `getChangedCells` works only if you use cell editing. Did you set `cellEdit` option of jqGrid to `true`?

Comment: Even by adding `grid.celledit.js` and setting `cellEdit` to `true`, it still not working

Comment: @user1810097: You should address the problem to `struts2` specialists. I added the corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: @Oleg: will the method getChangedCells() work with form editing as well? Or is it restricted to inline and cell editing?

Comment: @user1810097: All 3 editing modes are very different implemented. `getChangedCells` method works *only in case of cell editing*.